# To list column from table mentioned in sub query (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Consider the three tables - actors, roles and movies

```
mysql> DESCRIBE actors;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| first_name | varchar(100) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| last_name  | varchar(100) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| gender     | char(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.17 sec)

mysql> DESCRIBE roles;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| actor_id | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| movie_id | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| role     | varchar(100) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DESCRIBE movies;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| name      | varchar(100) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| year      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| rankscore | float        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The following query list the first_name and last_name of all actors acted in movie 'Schindler's List':

```
mysql> SELECT first_name, last_name FROM actors WHERE id IN
    -> (SELECT actor_id FROM roles WHERE movie_id IN
    -> (SELECT id FROM movies WHERE name='Schindler\'s List')
    -> ) ORDER BY first_name;
```

Suppose if I want to list the role played by the actors along with their first and last names, what will the best query to fetch the desired result set or output? It may be noted that the role is a column in roles table, which is in the Sub Query.

Comment: You have to use [INNER JOIN](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx) to get data from all tables.

Comment: You would not generally write queries using sub queries in this way as already mentioned you should be using joins..

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.first_name, a.last_name, r.role 
FROM actors a, roles r, movies m 
WHERE a.id = r.actor_id  and r.movie_id  = m.id and m.name='Schindler\'s List'
ORDER BY first_name;
```

or you can use by joins;

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.first_name, a.last_name, r.role 
FROM roles r 
  INNER JOIN  actors a ON a.id = r.actor_id 
  INNER JOIN movies m  ON r.movie_id  = m.id 
WHERE m.name='Schindler\'s List'
ORDER BY first_name;
```

Comment: *you can use by joins*: OP should use the modern join syntax, not the old one

Comment: Thank you Dr. X for the right information. I have earlier used JOIN for the specific task. SELECT a.first_name, a.last_name, r.role FROM actor a JOIN roles r ON a.id=r.actor_id JOIN movies m ON m.id=r.movie_id AND m.name='Schindler\'s List';  However there's an opinion that JOIN is time-consuming and, Sub Queries are the best choice. This created my dilemma.

Comment: If you use right or left join, this is a little bit different.